# How do I get the status code for a particular URL

Tags: java

I have a maven project with a controller and jsp with simple form data and recaptcha for verification. It works normally, but when I try to introduce a logic to get the status code of the google captcha api.js, I get this error in eclipse console.

Exception caught : Connection refused: connect

It goes to catch and proceeds further and displays the file properly.
But i am  not able to get the status code.
What to do?

```
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public ModelAndView firstPage() throws HttpException, IOException  {

    try{
        System.out.println("check 1");
        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
        System.out.println("check 2");
        HttpMethod method = new GetMethod("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js");
        int statusCode = httpclient.executeMethod(method);
        System.out.println(" statusCode : "+statusCode);
    } catch (ConnectException ce){
        System.out.println(" Exception caught : "+ce.getMessage());
    }


    return new ModelAndView("welcome");
```

Answer (score 2):

The status code is part of the HTTP protocol, if the connection cannot start then the HTTP session is not started so there's not status code